# Pandas error "need to escape, but no escapechar set" - for bullet points

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very weird error where the below field in my pandas dataframe gives me a "need to escape, but no escapechar set" error

```
df.to_csv(path,encoding="utf-8-sig",index=False)
```

The cell giving me trouble is the below, and i cant for the life of me figure out why:

My main responsibilities were:
● XXXXX.
● XXXXX.
XXXXX.
● XXXXX.
XXXXX.
● XXXXX.
XXXXX.
XXXXX.
● XXXXX.
● XXXXX..
● XXXXX.
● XXXXX.
● XXXXX.
XXXXX.
● XXXXX.
XXXXX.
● XXXXX.
● XXXXX.
XXXXX.
● XXXXX.

Am i missing something completely obvious? Another cell also gives me problem because it has \x00 in it, does that for some reason cause issues when saving to CSV using utf-8? I have never encountered that problem before.

I solved it "manually" by replacing all nulls, but I dont understand why they are a problem though

```
df.replace({'\x00': ''}, regex=True, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Probably you need to change your encoding. try latin-1 or utf8

Comment: I am already using utf-8 - i am just baffled that it cant write a 0 byte to file in csv